# Continuous positive function such that $\int\limits_1^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges, while $\int\limits_1^{\infty}f^2(x)dx$ diverges

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Does there exist a continuous positive function such that $\int\limits_1^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges, while $\int\limits_1^{\infty}f^2(x)dx$ diverges? I have proved that if $f$ is decreasing monotonically, then this is false and $\int\limits_1^{\infty}f^2(x)dx$, but what happens when the demand for monotonic drops?